# What's the difference between ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent and EnvironmentPostProcessor?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to create a property source to read properties from a database table. When looking for how to implement this, I found two approaches that requires to create the file `spring.factories` and register the specific class.

For instance, I could use `Events`, with `ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent`

```
public class DatabasePropertiesListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent> {
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent event) {
        ConfigurableEnvironment environment = event.getEnvironment();
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("spring.datasource.url", "<my value>"); // READ FROM DB AND CONFIGURE ALL PROPS HERE
        environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(new PropertiesPropertySource("dbProps", props));
    }
}
```

And `spring.factories` file:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener=com.DatabasePropertiesListener
```

Or to use an environment post processor with `EnvironmentPostProcessor`:

```
public class DatabasePropertiesEnvPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {
    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("spring.datasource.url", "<my value>"); // READ FROM DB AND CONFIGURE ALL PROPS HERE
        environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(new PropertiesPropertySource("dbProps", props));
    }
}
```

And `spring.factories` file:

```
 org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=com.DatabasePropertiesListener
```

I read the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-boot-application.html#howto-customize-the-environment-or-application-context) but still I'm not clear about what the pros and cons of using each approach are, when I should choose one over the other, or actually if there is a better way to do this. Can someone give me some clarifications about this?

Comment: Did you look at [`@PropertySource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html)? *"a convenient and declarative mechanism for adding a PropertySource to Spring's Environment."*

Comment: @Andreas, I did but I can only load properties files, from my case I want to read a DB table.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this?

Comment: @AmirAbiri unfortunately not, I think the differnece is the life cycle in spring, probably giving more access to different part of spring context